# Нужно вывести сумму квадратов всех чисел от a до b

Tags: c

Нужно ввести два целых числа a и b (a ≤ b) и вывести сумму квадратов всех чисел от a до b.
Пробовал вот так:

```
{int a,b,sum;
scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
do
{
    printf("%d ",sum+=a*a);
    a++;
}
while(a<=b);
return 0;
}
```

Код сам работает, но он мне выводит сумму квадратов всех чисел в промежутке между числами a и b и так до самого конца. Однако мне нужно, чтобы он вывел мне итоговую сумму. Не могли вы сказать, в чём заключается ошибка?

Answer (score 3):

Замените

```
printf("%d ",sum+=a*a)
```

на

```
sum+=a*a
```

а перед `return 0` вставьте

```
printf("%d ",sum);
```

P.S. А еще лучше

```
{
    int a,b;
    scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
    printf("%d\n",(a*(-1+(3-2*a)*a)+b*(1+b)*(1+2*b))/6);
}
```